# multi category in page PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

i have problem with multi category for page in php and mysql,
i have "Business" , "Category" and "Business_con_Category" tables in mysql.
the Business_con_Category table is connect between Business to Category,
so i think doing select multiple, and implode for add to table.

but my problem is editing how i can know if remove category and delete from table ?
i treid in to array old category and new category and compare, but is not work good..

do you have an idea

thanks!

Comment: Sorry, can't even decode the question.

Comment: very simply, if I add a page that has four categories it adds four rows in the table Business_con_Category, but now I'm editing the page and delete it 2 Categories How do I know to delete 2 rows from Business_con_Category?

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to not try to remove only some rows from `business_con_category`. Instead, remove all rows for the given business, and then add the rows with the categories that still should be present.

Comment: So are you saying I need every time I edit the page I need to delete the table Business_con_Category all rows related to that page and then add them again?

Comment: That is a possible solution, not the only solution. In case you're looking for something else, you should at least provide the code you already have.